# Build.gradle not accepting version code as string

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Version code updates for 1 to 9 as **string** but, when update to 10 gives compile time error :

```
Cannot cast object '10' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.lang.Integer'

    versionCode = "10"
```

If i make version code as integer 10, i am able to generate signed apk but not able to upload in play store.

project was initially made in eclipse later migrated to android studio

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode = 10
    versionName = "1.1.12"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

lintOptions {
    // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
    quiet true
    // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
    abortOnError false
    // if true, only report errors
    ignoreWarnings true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        zipAlignEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}




sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` file, showing where and how you are setting the `versionCode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a hunch that Gradle interpreted it as a char, and just assigned the ASCII code of the character `9` to the `versionCode` (and that's why it doesn't work with multiple characters, because then it is assumed as a string).

Since the ASCII code of the character `9` is 57, you should try uploading it with the **versionCode 58 or higher** (because Google Play does not allow downgrades).

Comment: yeah, i'll try that out

Answer (score 4):

```
Cannot cast object '10' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.lang.Integer'
```

1. **versionCode must be integer value .**
2. remove **`=`**

### android:versionCode

> An integer value that represents the version of
>   the application code, relative to other versions. The value is an
>   integer so that other applications can programmatically evaluate it,
>   for example to check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set
>   the value to any integer you want, however you should make sure that
>   each successive release of your application uses a greater value. The
>   system does not enforce this behavior, but increasing the value with
>   successive releases is normative.

```
  minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode  10
    versionName "1.1.12"
    multiDexEnabled true
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Run**.

**FYI**

```
 versionCode Integer.parseInt("10") // String to Integer convert
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the for `versionCode = "10"`
to this `versionCode 10`

Thats the default format